# kvm works only when kvm-intel is unloaded

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am new to kvm. I have this strange issue.
But before explaining the issue, here is my set up.

I try to install VM on my Host which is a Acer Laptop 5720 Intel Core 2 Duo T7500 processor. The cpu flags indicate that Virtualization is supported. I run Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) which comes with kvm.

Now coming to the issue - 
I dont get any errors while executing "sudo modprobe kvm-intel".
So I presume my processor does indeed support hardware virtualization.

I use virt-manager and create a VM on which I install ubuntu from an *.iso file.
When I start the VM it says it is running. No signs of any trouble. I can see the domain listed in "virsh list". But when I try to connect to the VM thru VNC, all I get to see is a blank screen (no cursor). There is no response to any key press. And I am unable to install the OS on the disc. Same happens when I try thru the commandline.

I changed the video mode etc. Tried all different combinations but nothing helps.
But strangely, if I shutdown the vm an virt-manager and then unload the module by doing
"sudo modprobe -r kvm-intel", everything works fine. ie., I can see the screen via VNC. I am able to install the OS and so on.

So what does this mean ? Is hardware virtualization not supported on my laptop ? How come there is no error anywhere ? dmesg | grep kvm doesnt report anything. Can someone throw light on what exactly is happening ?

Comment: After you start KVM, what does `lsmod` show? What KVM modules are loaded?

Also, if you run `kvm` from the command line without any options, do you get any error message?

Comment: lsmod | grep kvm shows the following output  
kvm_intel              39384  0   
kvm                   245405  1 kvm_intel  
  
  
simply running kvm on the console pops up a blank screen with the title "qemu"

Answer (score 1):

check your laptop bios - many vednors install VT enabled CPUs, but disable virtualization in the BIOS. That way the /proc/cpuinfo flags are OK, but kvm can't work properly

Comment: I tried running securable.exe. It reported that "Virtualization is Locked on". So i beleive it is enabled. My BIOS ( phoenix bios utility) provides no option to enable/disable VT.

Comment: try this http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=42782

Comment: KVM require to have hardware virtualization, and he says that he can use KVM, but has to unload the kvm-intel module.

Comment: unless this is a weird version of kvm, kvm_intel has to load as well as kvm

Comment: kvm -version outputs    
  

QEMU PC emulator version 0.12.3 (qemu-kvm-0.12.3), Copyright (c)   
2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard